# IIFE doesn't display console message?

Tags: javascript

When I run this IIFE function in the console or using it in document, it doesn't work, per definition it's immediately invoked, so why it's not showing anything on the console?

```js
(function(){ 
   console.log(8);
});
```

Comment: That's a function expression, but it's not invoked, immediately or otherwise. Add `()` before the last semicolon.

Comment: Related: [*What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript/8228308#8228308)

Answer (score 1):

You missed the execution part.

```js
(function(){ 
   console.log(8);
})(); // () needs to be added
```